# Checking two HashMaps for identical keyset in Rust

Tags: rust, iterator, equality

Suppose I have two HashMaps (or, *any* map structure that has keys mapping to something else), map1 and map2, and I want to ensure that they have an identical set of keys. Note that the *keys* are the same type in the maps, but the *values* are *not*.

My initial attempt at this was just:

```
map1.keys().eq(map2.keys())
```

and, although this worked the *first* time, the *eq* function for iterators (understandably) seems to compare the keys *in the order produced by the iterator, not by checking for the existence of a key anywhere in the second iterator*. This, combined with the fact that HashMap::keys() produces an iterator where the *order of the keys is non-deterministic* means that the equality function will often fail even if the sets (in the set-theory sense) of the keys are identical.

So, my next attempt was to make a function which did this:

```
fn keys_match<T:std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash,U,V>(map1:&HashMap<T,U>, map2:&HashMap<T,V>) -> bool {
  // Make sure that map1.keys() ⊆ map2.keys()
  for key in map1.keys() {
    match map2.get(key) {
      None => return false,
      Some(_) => {}
    }
  }
  // If map1.keys() ⊆ map2.keys() and their sizes equal, then the sets are equal
  map1.len() == map2.len()
}
```

Note for Rust beginners: My first try at this was actually with the knowledge that the keys in the maps were of type String, so my function signature was:

```
fn keys_match<T,U>(map1:&HashMap<String,T>, map2:&HashMap<String,U>) -> bool
```

until I realized that I could even genericize the *common key type* by requiring them to have the Eq and Hash traits.

**Question: Is there a more-terse way of doing this in Rust?**

Comment: Not an answer, but you should probably test the sizes first so that you won't waste time comparing the keys if the lengths are different.

Comment: Great suggestion. I think I got a little caught up in trying to limit early returns and limit the size of the code, but you're right, provided that HashMap::len() doesn't, itself, iterate over the keys (and depending upon whether your use case tends to mostly test same-sized-yet-different sets), testing the length first is an important consideration.

Answer (score 15):

> Is there a more-terse way of doing this in Rust?

```rust
fn keys_match<T: Eq + Hash, U, V>(
    map1: &HashMap<T, U>, 
    map2: &HashMap<T, V>,
) -> bool {
    map1.len() == map2.len() && map1.keys().all(|k| map2.contains_key(k))
}
```

([**Playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=99dff5fa7496b06a09895d34cbf07ed6))

This code has three improvements over your code:

- Using [`Iterator::all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all) shortens the code quite a bit.
- Using [`HashMap::contains_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.contains_key) is better than checking the result of `HashMap::get`.
- This checks the length first, as this is a cheap test and should be done first.

Comment: I had never come across the .all() function (nor the .any()) for iterators. I'll now know to look for this in other iterator-supporting languages.

Comment: @Jemenake Yeah, many methods of `Iterator` are just great and can really shorten your code. And make it more readable IMO :)

Comment: Might `map1.keys().any(|k| !map2.contains_key(k))` be more efficient (same worst case of performance of `O(n)`, but much better best case).

Comment: @TeymourAldridge There shouldn't be a difference. If the closure in `all` returns `false`, it also doesn't try any further and stops immediately. `all` and `any` are really just inverted versions of one another.

Comment: @TeymourAldridge No problem!